# Adding custom command to gradle script

Tags: java, gradle, shadowjar

I'm using the `shadowJar` plugin for Gradle (4.2.1) to build the so-called `fatJar` or `uberJar`. This works as expected but I would like to to add some actions after the building is done. More precisely, I'd like to make the resulting file executable (in `Unix` terms, i.e. `chmod +x`) and then copy it to a certain directory. I've googled a lot and I know that both task are possible. I'd like to know whether I should write a script (task) that runs `shadowJar` and then does what I want, or I should change the `shadowJar` itself to embed the operations I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good criteria to decide about such situation is to ask yourself if the new features are really part of the responsibility of the `shoadowJar`. If the answer is no, then it would be better to (as you mentioned) have another task that runs on top of that. By doing so you can reuse the `shadowJar` in much more different scenarios by combining it to other tasks. If you define the new one to be dependent on the `shadowJar`, then you would be sure that you can still call `shadowJar` task individually while calling the new task would always trigger the `shadowJar`. Your new task would be something like this:

```
task afterShadowJar (dependesOn: 'shadowJar') {
    // manipulate file permissions, etc.
}
```

Comment: I will go with creating new task then. Where should I put this new task? In `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes, you can just put it into the `build.gradle` of the module that the plugin is already being applied.